# EF/LINQ: Where() against a property of a subtype

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, covariance

I have a set of POCOs, all of which implement the following simple interface:

```
 interface IIdObject
 {
     int Id { get; set; }
 }
```

A subset of these POCOs implement this additional interface:

```
 interface IDeletableObject : IIdObject
 {
     bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
 }
```

I have a repository hierarchy that looks something like this:

> IRepository<T> <: BasicRepository<T> <: ValidatingRepository<T> (where T is IIdObject)

I'm trying to add a **FilteringRepository** to the hierarchy such that all of the POCOs that implement `IDeletableObject` have a `Where(p => p.IsDeleted == false)` filter applied before any other queries take place.  My goal is to avoid duplicating the hierarchy solely for IDeletableObjects.

My first attempt looked like this:

```
public override IQueryable<T> Query()
{
    return base.Query().Where(t => ((IDeletableObject)t).IsDeleted == false);
}
```

This works well with LINQ to Objects, but when I switch to an EF backend I get: *"LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types."*

I went on to try some fancier parameterized solutions, but they ultimately failed because I couldn't make T covariant in the following case for some reason I don't quite understand:

```
interface IQueryFilter<out T>  // error
{
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetFilter();
}
```

I'd be happy to go into more detail on my more complicated solutions if it would help, but I think I'll stop here for now in hope that someone might have an idea for me to try.

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: You have to use non-interface types for this. The EF doesn't know how to translate an interface implementation to SQL.

Comment: Can't you apply `where T : IDeletableObject` to type parameter? Inherit from `Repository` and create `DeletableRepository` with additional type constraint.

Comment: @Craig: if I use classes I unfortunately bump into multiple inheritance issues. :-(  @LukLed: right now I have a single rule in my IoC container for repository creation.  I believe making new repository types (or re-parameterizing them) will entail additional specification there, which I was hoping to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too big for comment, so...

You can create expressions dynamically. I've created helper methods:

```
public static class ExpressionHelper
{
    public static MemberExpression PropertyExpression(this Expression expr,string propertyName)
    {           
        var properties = propertyName.Split('.');

        MemberExpression expression = null;

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            if (expression == null)
                expression = Expression.Property(expr, property);
            else
                expression = Expression.Property(expression, property);
        }

        return expression;
    }

    public static BinaryExpression EqualExpression<T>(this Expression expr, string propertyName, T value)
    {
        return Expression.Equal(expr.PropertyExpression(propertyName), Expression.Constant(value, typeof(T)));
    }
}
```

Then you can use:

```
//Checking if T implements IDeletableObject
if (typeof(IDeletableObject).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
{
    //a
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "a");
    //a.IsDeleted == false
    var where = parameter.EqualExpression("IsDeleted", false);
    //a => a.IsDeleted == false
    var condition = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(where, parameter);
    list = list.Where(condition);
}
```

**EDIT**

You can also use [Dynamic Linq Library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx). It uses expressions too, but doesn't force you to think about how it all works, just write simple conditions as string. I don't know how it handles bool values.

Comment: Super interesting (and I greatly appreciate the hand-holding, heh).  I'll try this out ASAP!

Comment: @ladenedge: It should work fine, but may need some adjustments. I wasn't able to test it completely.

Comment: Well, I played a bit with your code here, but Dynamic Linq was just too easy, heh.  The resulting code looks like: `set.Where("IsDeleted == @0", false)` - very straightforward!

Thanks so much for your time and help!

Comment: @ladenedge: Playing a bit and then using dynamic linq was propably the best solution:)